# List manipulation based on entries

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to manipulate a List of  reals based of the value of each digit: 
If: current digit is <=2 - move to the next digit
Else: move to next digit and drop all of the reamining digits.

As I'm fairly unexperienced using Mathematica I attempted something like:

```
realdgts = RealDigits[1.21461]; (<- just any random real)
real = realdgts[[1]]; 
Do[{If[real[i] <= 3, Null, Drop[real, -i + 1]]}, {i, 
Length[real]}]
```

where I want the Do[...] to return a list satifying my  criteria. I somehow expected to find an easy solution employing an if-clause similar to the one in Java, but it appears like Mathematica is not optimized for such simple tasks. Ill need to do this in order to apply an special rule for rounding values.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is at the end but let's break it down to make it easier to follow.

```
realdgts = RealDigits[1.21461]
(* {{1, 2, 1, 4, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 1} *)

real = realdgts[[1]]
(* {1, 2, 1, 4, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} *)
```

Get the position of the members greater than 2.

```
First@First@Position[real, x_ /; x > 2]
(* 4 *)
```

It is a bit verbose but we want to use one less than that position so we can write:

```
realdgts[[1, 1;;First@First@Position[real, x_ /; x > 2] - 1]]
(* {1, 2, 1} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list = RealDigits[1.21461]
```

{{1, 2, 1, 4, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 1}

Using `SequenceSplit` (new in 11.3)

```
First @ SequenceSplit[list[[1]], {x_ /; x > 2}]
```

{1, 2, 1}

Answer (score 1):

**Using `TakeWhile`:**

```
realdgts = RealDigits[1.21461]
TakeWhile[First@realdgts, # <= 2 &]
```

{1, 2, 1}

Answer (score 1):

```
list = RealDigits[1.21461]:
```

Using `Extract`:

```
Extract[#, List /@ Most@*Range @@ FirstPosition[#, x_ /; x > 2]] & @ list[[1]]

(*{1, 2, 1}*)
```

Or using `SequenceCases`:

```
First @ SequenceCases[list[[1]], s : {__} /; And @@ Thread[s <= 2]]

(*{1, 2, 1}*)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
count = 1;

real[[1 ;; Catch[Scan[If[# <= 3 , count = count + 1, Throw[count + 1]] &, real]]]]
```

or

```
real[[1 ;; Position[real, x_ /; x > 2, 2][[2, 1]]]]
```